# How to manage global states with React Query

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query, supabase

i have a project that's using Nextjs and Supabase. I was using context API and now i'm trying to replace it for React Query, but i'm having a hard time doing it. First of all, can i replace context completely by React Query?

I created this hook to get the current user

```
export const getUser = async (): Promise<Profile> => {
  const onFetch = await supabase.auth.getUser();
  const userId = onFetch.data.user?.id;
  let { data, error } = await supabase
    .from("profiles")
    .select()
    .eq("id", userId)
    .single();

  return data;
};

export const useUser = () => {
  return useQuery(["user"], () => getUser());
};
```

I'm not sure how to trigger it. When i was using context i was getting the user as this. If data, then it would redirect to the HomePage

```
let { data, error, status } = await supabase
      .from("profiles")
      .select()
      .eq("id", id)
      .single();

    if (data) {
      setUser(data);
      return true;
    }
```

Since i was getting the user before redirecting to any page, when i navigated to profile page, the user was already defined. How can i get the user before anything and keep this state? I suppose that once the user is already defined, at the profile component i can call useUser and just use it's data. But it's giving me undefined when i navigate to profile, i suppose that it's fetching again.

```
  const { data, isLoading } = useUser();
```

Comment: You can use the [useQueryClient](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/reference/useQueryClient) hook inside the components that require the user data and access this data like so: `const user = queryClient.getQueryData(['user'])`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But it's giving me undefined when i navigate to profile, i suppose that it's fetching again.

Once data is fetched when you call `useUser`, it will not be removed anymore (unless it can be garbage collected after it has been unused for some time). So if you do a client side navigation (that is not a full page reload) to another route, and you call `useUser` there again, you should get data back immediately, potentially with a background refetch, depending on your `staleTime` setting).

If you're still getting undefined, one likely error is that you are creating your `QueryClient` inside your app and it thus gets re-created, throwing the previous cache away. You're not showing how you do that so it's hard to say. Maybe have a look at these FAQs: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-fa-qs#2-the-queryclient-is-not-stable

Comment: Yes! I created the queryClient inside the _app.tsx. Once i created it above the component, it worked. Although it's working, i'm getting this error.  ```Query data cannot be undefined. Please make sure to return a value other than undefined from your query function. Affected query key: ["user"]```. How can i solve it?